# Indexing on ANY queries

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, postgresql-15

I have a table that I am trying to query. Here is the create statement for the table

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.TableName
   (
       i integer NOT NULL,
       t integer NOT NULL,
       v real NOT NULL,
       h smallint NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT TableName_key_i_t_h UNIQUE (i, t, h)
   )
```

The indexing is done using the unique constraint. My query is as below. It appears not to be using the indexing. What am I doing wrong?

```
aggregate_minpower_query = f"""select i, min(p) from {tileTableName} 
            where  
            i = ANY (%(iList)s) and
            t = ANY (%(tList)s) and
            h < (%(hval)s) 
            group by i"""
```

Should I be using IN?

```
aggregate_minpower_query = f"""select i, min(p) from {tileTableName} 
            where  
            i IN %(iList)s and
            t IN %(tList)s and
            h < (%(hval)s) 
            group by i"""
```

---

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 2):

Put the column for which the condition is most selective first in the constraint definition. Experiment with `enable_seqscan = off` to see if PostgreSQL is right if it thinks that using an index won't make the query faster. – [Laurenz Albe](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/176905/laurenz-albe)